# Querying Excel Worksheets using LinQ - LinQToExcel

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using LinQToExcel to read my excel worksheets.ExcelQueryFactory has a  method that returns a worksheet based on worksheet name(Only one value(Name) is allowed).There is also a method that returns WorkSheet names. Is there a way to use LinQ to select multiple worksheet collection based on names.

ExcelQueryFactory test = new ExcelQueryFactory(FilePath);
        List names = targetExcelFactory.GetWorksheetNames().ToList();
        var sheet =  test.Worksheet("sheet1");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerable.Select lets you turn the result from one set into a completely other set aka projection.

```
var result = targetExcelFactory.GetWorksheetNames()
  .Select(name => test.Worksheet(name))
  .ToList();
```